# jquery slidetoggle image swap

Tags: jquery, image, swap, slidetoggle

I'm trying to get slideToggle to swap images based on if a div is expanded or collapsed.  I have it working one way, where it will change an image from plus to minus, but it only works on one div and I have multiple and it only works once.  It doesn't toggle.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".content").toggle(1);
$(".expand").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(400);

    if ($(".image1").attr('src', "../nathan/plus.png")) {
        $(".image1").attr(
            'src', 
            $(".image1").attr('src').replace('plus', 'minus')
        );
    } else {
        $(".image1").attr(
            'src', 
            $(".image1").attr('src').replace('minus', 'plus')
        );
    }
});
});
```

The IndexOf() works, but if I was to duplicate the divs they all change when one is clicked.  Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="list">
<h2 class="expand">Title1<img class="image1" src="../nathan/plus.png"></h2>
<div class="content">
</div>
</div>

<div class="list">
<h2 class="expand">Title2<img class="image1" src="../nathan/plus.png"></h2>
<div class="content">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your html ?

Comment: figuring out why this partially works would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the setter method to check your `src'

```
if ($(".image1").attr('src', "../nathan/plus.png"))
```

instead use

```
if ($(".image1").attr('src') == "../nathan/plus.png"))
```

Or even better just check if the source contains the image using [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if ($(".image1").attr('src').indexOf("plus.png") > -1)
```

**EDIT:**

You can probably do it like this to prevent all from changing - this is the context the to look for the image

```
$(".expand").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(400);
    var $img = $(".image1", this);
    if ($img.attr('src').indexOf("plus.png") > -1) {
        $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace('plus', 'minus'));
    } else {
        $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace('minus', 'plus'));
    }
});​
```

so

```
$(".image1", this);
```

would be the same as

```
$(this).find('.image1');
```

Comment: @ja408 I updated my answer to help you specifically choose which one to toggle